How to exclude app module from instrumented test?
After running ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest and removing androidTest directory and the any required setup with instrumented test from my app module build.gradle.kts, the task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest still get executed.
Removed from build.gradle.kts
defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner = "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian.HiltTestRunner"
}

dependencies {

    androidTestImplementation(libs.runner)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.truth.ext)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.google.truth)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.test.core.ktx)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

}

I have a very specific problem where the app-debug.apk generated from task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest keeps failing to install in an AVD running in a CI CD pipeline, thus I am trying to exclude it.
I also tried to specify which module runs instrumented test yet it keeps running the task for app module.
./gradlew module1:connectedAndroidTest module2:connectedAndroidTest 


